# Arraylist for images (drawable)

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to show images upon clicking a button.

These images must come from an array so that i can easily add or delete images without having to edit all of my code.

However the compiler aborts my build and i have 2 errors.

```
public void showQuestion()
    {
        currentQuestion++;
        imageNumber++;
        if(currentQuestion == questions.length)
            currentQuestion = 0;
        if(imageNumber == myImageList.length)
            imageNumber = 0;
        questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);
        answerView.setText("");
        answerText.setText("");
        imagesview.setImageResource(myImageList[imageNumber]);
    }
```

the first error is at `imageNumber == myImageList.length`, saying 
Multiple markers at this line

- length cannot be resolved or is not a field
- `myImageList` cannot be resolved to a variable

the second error is on images `view.setimageResource(myImageList[imageNumber]);`

Multiple markers at this line

- The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to       `ArrayList<Integer>`
- `myImageList` cannot be resolved to a variable

Edit:
The mistake i made was i overlooked that i was using an INT with the .length attribute. and a set instead of a .get!

Hope it helps

Comment: that is an string with text. like ; questions = new String[]{"What is the capital of France?"};

Comment: Switching it to myImageList.size() will help with the first issue. Switching it to view.setImageResource(myImageList.get(imageNumber); will help with the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ArrayList` is of type `list`. Therefore `.length` should be `.size()` and `myImageList[imageNumber]` should be `myImageList.get(imageNumber)`.